# How to strip punctionation only if it's the last character

Tags: python, string, strip, punctuation

I know I can use `.translate(None, string.punctuation)` to strip punctuation from a string. However, I'm wondering if there's a way to strip punctuation only if it it's the final character.

For example: 
`However, only strip the final punctuation.` -> `However, only strip the final punctuation`

and `This is sentence one. This is sentence two!` -> `This is sentence one. This is sentence two`

and `This sentence has three exclamation marks!!!` -> `This sentence has three exclamation marks`

I know I could write a while loop to do this but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant/efficient way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply use [`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

> #### `str.rstrip([chars])`
>
> Return a copy of the string with trailing characters removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace. The chars argument is not a suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped:

```
>>> import string

>>> s = 'This sentence has three exclamation marks!!!'
>>> s.rstrip(string.punctuation)
'This sentence has three exclamation marks'

>>> s = 'This is sentence one. This is sentence two!'
>>> s.rstrip(string.punctuation)
'This is sentence one. This is sentence two'

>>> s = 'However, only strip the final punctuation.'
>>> s.rstrip(string.punctuation)
'However, only strip the final punctuation'
```

Answer (score -1):

`re.sub(r'[,;\.\!]+$', '', 'hello. world!!!')`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it's probably better to include more context/explanation.

Comment: Well, it is simple enough. Just call the `re.sub()` method, with a regular expression that removes the punctuation signs in the end of the string — exactly as written.